# Mix NSXPCConnection and xpc C API

Tags: objective-c, xpc, nsxpcconnection

I am working with XPC services using `NSXPCConnection` wrapper, and since the Objective-C wrapper can't handle `IOSurfaceRef` objects, I would like to make some direct functions calls to the C API defined in xpc.h. But I can't find a way to retrieve the underlying `xpc_connection_t` reference (as I can see in NSXPCConnection.h, there is a private ivar called `_xconnection` that could be the reference I need).
Am I missing something stupid, or can't the Objective-C wrapper and the C API simply be used together?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, but `XPCKit` offers such a conversion mechanism AND it's 10.7 compatible.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure I understand you. What kind of conversion does XPCKit offer? IOSurfaceRef is not supported (it is in the wishlist), and it does not seem to offer a way to get a NSXPCConnection from a xpc_connecion_t reference. It seems to be an alternative to NSXPCConnection wrapper, but without IOSurface support too.

Comment: When you configure your `XPCConnection` object, use its `.connection` property, and call `IOSurfaceLookupFromXPCObject()` with a received object. Bonus: since it's open source, you can even create add this to the `NSObject+XPCParse` category.

Comment: Ok. This is of help for me, even if it doesn't answer to the original question (how to retrieve the underlying xpc_connection_t of an NSXPCConnection object). Thank you!

Comment: Sorry! :P There's no way to do that, unless you'd like to try a runtime hack or two.